# How does boost::serialization Archive::register_type work?

Tags: c++, boost, types, polymorphism, registration

`boost::serialization` is able to serialize my polymorphic objects of their most-derived class even if these objects are pointed by a reference/pointer to the base class. This without needing virtual functions.

To be able to do that, `boost::serialization` requires to know about existent polymorphic types: `Archive::register_type` must be called on the `Archive` object used to serialize.

[This example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/serialization/example/demo.cpp) shows how to register types and how to serialize them.

---

I'm wondering how this is achieved.
I tried to look at `boost::serialization` source code but failed: I'm not that good with template metaprogramming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`boost.serialization` can write out your polymorphic class by using either `typeid()` or some user defined function `get_key` that returns the actual type of the polymorphic object.

`register_type` works by using the type supplied to instantiate a template that allows the archive to map the type identifier (either `typeid(T)` or the result of `T::get_key()`) to an object that knows how to serialize `T`.

Answer (score 1):

boost::serialization uses the RTTI features of C++ to dynamically determine the type of an object.

You can look "typeid" function to determine dinamically the type of a class, even having only the base class pointer.

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/RTTI

Comment: Yes, I guessed RTTI were used, but how does register_type use it?